# Output sql query into html table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to place the output of this PHP SQL query into a database table, but it is outputting all of the row data into one column.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = htmlentities($_POST['name']);
    $parts = explode(" ", $name);
    $lastname = array_pop($parts);
    $firstname = implode(" ", $parts);

    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password");

    mysql_select_db("shoretoshore", $connection);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT ship_no, shipment_id, arrival_date, origin,      destination, lname, fname from shipment, captain WHERE captain.capt_id=shipment.capt_id AND captain.fname='$firstname' AND captain.lname='$lastname'", $connection);

    echo '<table border="0" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="1px" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:11px; background-color:#E1E1E1" width="100%">
            <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-weight:bold">
            <th>Shipment No.</th>
            <th>Shipment Id.</th>
            <th>Arrival Date</th>
            <th>Origin</th>
            <th>Destination</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            </tr>';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        foreach ($row as $value)
            print "<tr><td>"."{$value}"."</td></tr>";
        echo "<br>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

How do I output the results of the query into an HTML table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting the `$value` inside quotation marks, it will be treated as string.

Try:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($row as $value)
    {
      echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: The quotation marks were fine. It's the `<tr>` that needs to be outside the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain the issue you're having. But from what I can see off the bat, you're looping through all the values of the row and outputting them as rows itself, instead of as a cell within the table row. The curly brackets around value are unnecessary as well, since you are concatenating the strings, you can just do `'<tr><td>'.$value.'</td></tr>'` OR `"<tr><td>$value</td></tr>"`. PHP will parse variables within a string if the string is double quoted. I would also refrain from adding `<br>` tags as direct children of a table. If you need spacing between table rows, use padding and margins.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {

    print "<tr><td>".$row[0]."</td></tr>";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're outputting a `<tr>` tag for every row *and* column. You need to move the `<tr>` outside the inner loop.

Technically, you don't need to concatenate `"{$value}"` with the other two strings, but you really should pass `$value` through [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to avoid producing incorrect HTML if the value contains any `<` or `&` characters. Eg:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    print '<tr>';
    foreach ($row as $value) {
        $v = htmlspecialchars ($value);
        print "<td>$v</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

Also, you're not supposed to have a `<br>` element between table rows, which is why I replaced it with a newline above. Personally, I would skip the closing `</td>` and `</tr>` tags since they are optional in HTML.

Note also, that the MySQL extension is deprecated and no longer maintained. You should be using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) these days.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
echo '<tr>';
foreach ($row as $value)
{
  echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing! Answers on Stack Overflow are expected to provide some context explaining what their code does and why it works. It can also be helpful to show why the asker’s code wasn’t working.